Django test if all objects that refer to an object have a certain "flag"?
When I need to test if an object isn't reffered to anymore I could use
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    retired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    modelA = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelA,
    )


ModelA.objects.filter(~Q(modelb__isnull=False))

The "weird" format of using negation and testing for False makes sure an Exists statement is created instead of a subquery or join.
However how would I test if "ModelA is only used in instances of ModelB that have retired=True", or are not referred to at all.

first step - use related_name in ForeignKey field.
class ModelB(models.Model):
    retired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    modelA = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelA,
        related_name="modelb"
    )


second step - use needed stuff in filters
# if u need not-retired modelb
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__isnull=False, modelb__retired=False)

# if u need retired or null-retired variant 1
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__isnull=False, modelb__retired__in=(True, None))

# if u need retired or null-retired variant 2
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__isnull=False).exclude(modelb__retired=False)

# if u need to keep your weird format
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__retired=False, ~Q(modelb__isnull=False))

I suggest YOU, THE READER, always use related_name on ForeignKey, ManyToMany, OneToOne etc.
Makes your life easier, and your code more readable.

Amen to "always use related_name"

Remember, folks. related_name is DOPE
